# macbook information in macos swift

Tags: swift, macos, terminal, mdm

I am building a macOS application. In which I need to retrieve information like

- Macbook name
- Apple Id
- OS version

& etc. Is it possible to retrieve information in macOS. if it is possible then how can we do this in swift macOS app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the name you can use something like this

```
if let deviceName = Host.current().localizedName {
       print(deviceName)
    }
```

for apple id on mac i am not sure but on iphone is `UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString` you can search for it or try this one, i have never developed mac book app

```
var systemVersion = NSProcessInfo.processInfo().operatingSystemVersion
```

is for the os version

Answer (score 0):

**For the name you could use:**

```
if let deviceName = Host.current().localizedName {
   print(deviceName)
}
```

**For the system :**

```
var systemVersion = NSProcessInfo.processInfo().operatingSystemVersion
```

For the Apple Id I'm not sure at all but I guess you cannot for security questions I guess. You need to check that up I don't know.